# Wrong number of items passed - Adding to dataframe column a numpy array content

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following `sioma_df` data frame:

[image]

These are the `sioma_df` shape and column index. It has 13807 rows and 37 columns:

```
sioma_df.columns
(13807, 37)
Index(['Luz (lux)', 'Precipitación (ml)', 'Temperatura (°C)',
       'Velocidad del Viento (km/h)', 'E', 'N', 'NE', 'NO', 'O', 'S', 'SE',
       'SO', 'PORVL2N1', 'PORVL2N2', 'PORVL4N1', 'PORVL5N1', 'PORVL6N1',
       'PORVL7N1', 'PORVL8N1', 'PORVL9N1', 'PORVL10N1', 'PORVL13N1',
       'PORVL14N1', 'PORVL15N1', 'PORVL16N1', 'PORVL16N2', 'PORVL18N1',
       'PORVL18N2', 'PORVL18N3', 'PORVL18N4', 'PORVL21N1', 'PORVL21N2',
       'PORVL21N3', 'PORVL21N4', 'PORVL21N5', 'PORVL24N1', 'PORVL24N2'],
      dtype='object')
```

I want to apply ***k*-means** algorithm and I've decided that in the random initialization phase I will have **`k=9` centroids**

```
# Turn the dataframe to numpy array
sioma_numpy = sioma_df.get_values()

k=9

# Create a dictionary with the centroids coordinates 
centroids = {
    i + 1: [np.random.randint(0, np.max(sioma_numpy)), np.random.randint(0, np.max(sioma_numpy))]
    for i in range(k)
}
```

I plot my data before to apply clustering

```
# I get each column individually into an array 

c1 = sioma_df['Luz (lux)'].values
c2 = sioma_df['Precipitación (ml)'].values
c3 = sioma_df['Temperatura (°C)'].values
c4 = sioma_df['Velocidad del Viento (km/h)'].values
c5 = sioma_df['PORVL2N1'].values
c6 = sioma_df['PORVL2N2'].values
c7 = sioma_df['PORVL4N1'].values
c8 = sioma_df['PORVL5N1'].values
c9 = sioma_df['PORVL6N1'].values
c10 = sioma_df['PORVL7N1'].values
c11 = sioma_df['PORVL8N1'].values
c12 = sioma_df['PORVL9N1'].values
c13 = sioma_df['PORVL10N1'].values
c14 = sioma_df['PORVL13N1'].values
c15 = sioma_df['PORVL14N1'].values
c16 = sioma_df['PORVL15N1'].values
c17 = sioma_df['PORVL16N1'].values
c18 = sioma_df['PORVL16N2'].values
c19 = sioma_df['PORVL18N1'].values
c20 = sioma_df['PORVL18N2'].values
c21 = sioma_df['PORVL18N3'].values
c22 = sioma_df['PORVL18N4'].values
c23 = sioma_df['PORVL18N4'].values
c24 = sioma_df['PORVL21N1'].values
c25 = sioma_df['PORVL21N2'].values
c26 = sioma_df['PORVL21N3'].values
c27 = sioma_df['PORVL21N4'].values
c28 = sioma_df['PORVL21N5'].values
c29 = sioma_df['PORVL24N1'].values
c30 = sioma_df['E'].values
c31 = sioma_df['N'].values
c32 = sioma_df['NE'].values
c33 = sioma_df['NO'].values
c34 = sioma_df['O'].values
c35 = sioma_df['S'].values
c36 = sioma_df['SE'].values
c37 = sioma_df['S'].values

""" I generate the X and Y coordinates points of previous c1 to c36 
variables above. With zip I've associate between each Ci and store in 
a list to will represent array X and array Y
"""
X = np.array(list(zip(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,c18)))
print( " ARRAY X" +'\n', X, '\n' )
Y = np.array(list(zip(c19,c20,c21,c22,c23,c24,c25,c26,c27,c28,c29,c30,c31,c32,c33,c34,c35,c36,)))
print( " ARRAY Y" +'\n', Y, '\n' )
```

Then, I've generated the pair x,y centroids coordinates.

I want to start with the assignment stage where I assign data points to the closest centroid. I have the following:

```
def assignment(df, centroids):
    # We take the k=9 centroids keys to iterations based
    for i in centroids.keys():
        # sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 - (y1 - y2)^2)
        # I want create a new column in a sioma_df dataframe named 
        #distance_from_i
        sioma_df['distance_from_{}'.format(i)] = (
            # We calculate the distances between each data point and 
            # each one of the 9 centroids

            # The distance_from_i column will have the distance value 
            # of each data point with reference to each centroid  (Are 9 in total) 
            np.sqrt(
                (X - centroids[i][0]) ** 2
                + (Y - centroids[i][1]) ** 2
            )
        )
    # We iterate by each distance value of each data point i with 
    # reference to each centroid j to compare and meet to what 
    # distance is more closest 
    centroid_distance_cols = ['distance_from_{}'.format(i) for i in centroids.keys()]
    # We create the closest column in the sioma_df dataframe,  
    # selecting the more minimum values in the column axis=1:
    sioma_df['closest'] = sioma_df.loc[:, centroid_distance_cols].idxmin(axis=1)
    sioma_df['closest'] = sioma_df['closest'].map(lambda x: int(x.lstrip('distance_from_')))
    sioma_df['color'] = sioma_df['closest'].map(lambda x: colmap[x])
    return df

# We wxecute the assignment function which perform the compute of what data point is more closest to each centroid
df = assignment(sioma_df, centroids)
print(df.head)
```

But when I execute my code I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'distance_from_1'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-160-b96e0351c13d> in <module>()
     24 
     25 # 
---> 26 df = assignment(sioma_df, centroids)
     27 print(df.head)

<ipython-input-160-b96e0351c13d> in assignment(df, centroids)
     11             np.sqrt(
     12                 (X - centroids[i][0]) ** 2
---> 13                 + (Y - centroids[i][1]) ** 2
     14             )
     15         )


ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 18, placement implies 1
```

This suggests that you are attempting to put too many data in too few memory positions. In this case, the value on the right of the equation In this case in

```
sioma_df['distance_from'] = np.sqrt((X - centroids[i][0]) ** 2 + (Y - centroids[i][1]) ** 2)
```

I don't really understand how to solve this inconvenient in the sense of have a correct allocation; which is making it difficult for me to troubleshoot.

Any support that point me in the correct direction will be highly appreciated

Comment: You should ***really*** use something like a dictionary to store all of those arrays.  Much cleaner

Comment: @user3483203 It's true, but, I am using these  **ci** arrays to apply them the zip function, and generate the `X` and `Y` coordinates to use later on a scatter function. Having `X` and `Y` elements in a dictionary, how to can I use in the scatter function? Or you tell me that use dictionary to compute my distances? precisely in where I get the error?

Answer (score 0):

My issue is that the `np.sqrt(…)` statement does not return a 1-dimensional array.
Each row ,col position is expecting 1 value but it is receiving an array that is 18 elements long, due to lenght of `X` and `Y` numpy arrays.

Operations on numpy arrays are element wise, and therefore might no change the shape of the array being operated on. 
Then When I want create the new `distance_from_i` column and make this:

```
sioma_df['distance_from_{}'.format(i)] = (
            np.sqrt(
                (X - centroids[i][0]) ** 2
                + (Y - centroids[i][1]) ** 2
            )
        )
```

I am assigning to this `distance_from_i` column, not a 1-dimensional array which is the capacity to have to receive or accept, else, that my `distance_from_i` column (each row, col) receive an array that is 18 elements long, and this is the reason of the error

`ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 18, placement implies 1`

Then, I’ve initialized my new `distance_from_i` column to `NaN` values before to assign it the result value of `np.sqrt(…)` statement and it works. My assignment function works O.K and has been the stayed of this way:

```
def assignment(df, centroids):
    # We take the k=9 centroids keys to iterations based
    for i in centroids.keys():
        # sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 - (y1 - y2)^2) 
        # We calculate the distances between each data point and 
        # each one of the 9 centroids

        # The distance_from_i column will have the distance value 
        # of each data point with reference to each centroid  (Are 9 in total) 
        n = np.sqrt(
                (X - centroids[i][0]) ** 2
                + (Y - centroids[i][1]) ** 2
        )
        # I want create a new column in a sioma_df dataframe named 
        # distance_from_i
        sioma_df['distance_from_{}'.format(i)] =  np.nan 
        sioma_df['distance_from_{}'.format(i)] =  n

    # We iterate by each distance value of each data point i with 
    # reference to each centroid j to compare and meet to what 
    # distance is more closest 
    centroid_distance_cols = ['distance_from_{}'.format(i) for i in centroids.keys()]

    # We create the closest column in the sioma_df dataframe,  
    # selecting the more minimum values in the column axis=1
    sioma_df['closest'] = sioma_df.loc[:, centroid_distance_cols].idxmin(axis=1)
    sioma_df['closest'] = sioma_df['closest'].map(lambda x: int(x.lstrip('distance_from_')))
    sioma_df['color'] = sioma_df['closest'].map(lambda x: colmap[x])
    return df

# We execute the assignment function which perform the compute of what data point is more closest to each centroid
df = assignment(sioma_df, centroids)
print(df.head)
```